# Passing and modifying a global array

Tags: java, arrays

### **NOTE**

### This is an example of not thoroughly debugging code before checking StackOverflow. An error elsewhere in the code was throwing this part off. There's nothing really "wrong" with this stuff here...so, feel free to use this as an example. No further answers needed :) Thanks!

Here's some code:

```
public static int[] code = new int[95];

//main method, array is populated with other methods, etc...

checkOrientation(code);

public static void checkOrientation(int[]code) {
        if (code[4] != 0) {
            System.out.println("Upside down!");
            for (int i = 4; i < code.length-6; ++i) {
                if (code[i] == 1) {
                    code[i] = 0;
                } else {
                    code[i] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering how to pass that global array and modify it. So, the goal is code reusability, that I could pass ANY array to this method and have it work.

Perhaps I need to have it return an array and assign that to a new array? I'd prefer not to make more arrays, my code is already getting a little bloated with array copies from various mutations.

Also: staying away from ArrayLists for now, so I'm not going to use them.

Any advice would be appreciated :)

**CLARIFICATION:**
What this code is doing is flipping the bits...so if array element [5] is a 1, it changes array element [5] to a 0, and vice versa. So, I'd like to keep it in the same array since it's not changing size and I won't need the original array anymore.

Comment: Modifying the contents of the array or changing the array object itself (e.g., a new size)?

Comment: Ah, good clarification. What this code is doing is flipping the bits...so if array element [5] is a 1, it changes array element [5] to a 0, and vice versa. So, I'd like to keep it in the same array since it's not changing size and I won't need the original array anymore.

Comment: You're already passing the array as an argument. What do you want to do that you aren't doing already? (The fact that the argument and the global array are both named `code` is confusing, but inside the method, the reference is always to the argument.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is *shadowing* your global variable `code` by using a function argument with the same name. In your function, `code` will refer to the passed argument, not to the global variable. Since the variable has global scope, you do not need to pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) As it turns out, my brain is being flatulent at the moment, and I've got a logic error in another spot of my code that is preventing this from running properly in the first place. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
void run()
{       
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    twiddle(arr);
    for (int i : arr)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

static void twiddle(int[] toBeTwiddled)
{
    toBeTwiddled[2] = 10;
}
```

Calling `run()` prints:

```
1
2
10
4
5
```

Did you try your code? It looks like it should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeah...found a logic bug elsewhere that prevented that code from running correctly. That's my bad.